# messagebox display before window is destroyed

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm writing a Win32 program and trying to display a messagebox before terminating the program. I want it to display the error and then close after the user reads the error and presses OK.

Here is what I have tried:

```
MessageBoxA(hwnd, "An Error occured! Please restart the program and try again.", "Error", MB_ICONERROR);
PostQuitMessage(0);

MessageBoxA(0, "An Error occured! Please restart the program and try again.", "Error", MB_ICONERROR);
PostQuitMessage(0);

MessageBoxA(hwnd, "An Error occured! Please restart the program and try again.", "Error", MB_ICONERROR);
DestroyWindow(hwnd);

MessageBoxA(0, "An Error occured! Please restart the program and try again.", "Error", MB_ICONERROR);
DestroyWindow(hwnd);
```

where `hwnd` is my application's main (and only) window. Not only does it not display the messagebox, it doesn't terminate the program immediately. I can hear many consecutive beeping sounds as though many messageboxes are being created but I don't see them.

How can I change the code so that the messagebox appears, the user presses OK, and then the program terminates immediately?

I am handling WM_CLOSE and WM_DESTROY in my main WndProc as so:

```
case WM_CLOSE:
    DestroyWindow(hwnd);
    return 0;

case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;
```

Comment: Since it isn't provided (hint: it should be) is this in the handler for WM_DESTROY for your main window handle proc? If so, can you include that in your WndProc, or a reproducible WndProc stripped down to the same problem?

Comment: The messagebox code I posted above isn't in a WndProc at all. That code is elsewhere, where I detect the error. But I have edited my post to include how I am handling WM_CLOSE and WM_DESTROY in my main WndProc.

Comment: Have you debugged your program to make sure that the MessageBoxA() function is getting run at all, and that the program is quitting on that line?

Comment: And if it *is* being called, have you checked GetLastError() if the MB call returned 0 to indicate a failed call? It will likely assist in determining the problem. Documented return codes are [in the documentation of `MessageBox()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I set a breakpoint on the MessageBox call and something strange happened. After pressing F10 (Step Over) it continued to execute the same MessageBox line 23 times, beeping each time. I called GetLastError() after the MessageBox() call and it returned 0.

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear. I continued to hit F10 and it continued to execute the same MessageBox line.I hit F10 23 times and it executed the MessageBox call 23 times, but no messagebox appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this approach (you an easily prompt for a response and then decide whether or not to call EndDialog)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "resource.h"

HINSTANCE hInst;

BOOL CALLBACK DlgMain(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
    }
    return TRUE;

    case WM_CLOSE:
    {
        MessageBox(hwndDlg, "An Error occured! Please restart the program and try again.", "Error", MB_ICONERROR);
        EndDialog(hwndDlg, 0);
    }
    return TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}


int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    hInst=hInstance;
    InitCommonControls();
    return DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(DLG_MAIN), NULL, (DLGPROC)DlgMain);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have shown the message, simply call [`ExitProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682658.aspx).